# NAudio - WaveHeaderUnprepared calling waveOutWrite

Tags: c#, naudio

What does it mean? Where is the problem? It appears when I'm closing my application. Of course I call dispose etc. It happens not always, but only sometimes.

Comment: next time, try not to add so many details.

Comment: That one in title: "WaveHeaderUnprepared calling waveOutWrite"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

waveOutWrite is a windows API which NAudio is calling and WaveHeaderUnprepared is one of the error codes it can return. Possibly your WAV playback has not quite finished before you close your application. Which callback model are you using?

Comment: I use default constructor from gui - window callback.